# Developing ArcGIS 9 extension - what do I need to get started?

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects

I got the 'honor' to port an existing ArcGis 3.x Avenue script to ArcGIS 9.x ArcObjects.

What do I need to get started? (So far I don't even have a copy of ArcGIS)

From [ESRI's developer website](http://edn.esri.com/) it seems I need to buy an EDN annual subscription for $1,500 - does this contain a developers copy of ArcGIS, or will I have to buy that, too?

The two Avenue scripts I need to port are rather small: one selects shapes for some searchterms it gets via OLE/DDE, one sends the selected shapes to another OLE/DDE application.
As far as I understand ArcObjects I will probably drop OLE/DDE and just call the appropriate objects via COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is another $500 for a ArcGIS Desktop license - http://store.esri.com/esri/showdetl.cfm?SID=2&Product_ID=1046&Category_ID=168

You'll then need to make a DLL that contains a custom tool that can be added to the desktop application. .NET / Visual Studio is probably the best approach.

You can prototype the application in VBA directly in the map document - this makes it easier to debug and test, but VBA will be phased out after version 9.4 so not a long term solution.

By the sound of your application I would investigate using SQL Server 2008 Spatial, or Oracle XE instead of ArcObjects. You could do most of the sptatial queries in the database and use .NET and a web mapping API for the front end. It would be far more flexible this way.

Comment: Creating a .NET custom tool walkthrough can be found at  http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/concepts_start.htm#01c01659-cdf8-4579-9c87-2b965e872d84.htm

Comment: ArcGis 9.x is a given which I am in no position to change - the customers get the license for ArcGIS and the data in ArcGIS-Format - I don't have the power to change the choice of software in this case.
But using VS/.Net sounds great. And it's good to know I need to buy the ArcGIS desktop license - customers don't like surprise expenses.